# How do I find the .NET Framework Path?

Tags: c#

In my program I current have the path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" hard-coded. I need it to dynamically load DLLs for reflection only.

Is there a registry key or environmental value I could use to avoid hard-coding this?

Comment: Aparently `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` has a `InstallRoot` key.

Comment: I'm sure there is probably a better way to do whatever it is you are attempting to do; It's not clear what it is you are trying to accomplish but it seems odd that you would need to use reflection on a .NET framework assembly....

Comment: @AndrewCounts When using reflection-only assembly loading you have consider search paths. Otherwise it won't know if you want the .NET or Silverlight or [...] versions of the assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(
    new Uri(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(string)).CodeBase).LocalPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeenvironment.getruntimedirectory(v=vs.100).ASPX) method:

```
// Show the path where the CLR was loaded from.
Console.WriteLine("Runtime directory: {0}", RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory());
```